# Push notifications work on Chrome Desktop but not on PWA on Android Phone

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

If I visit my site on Desktop, add permission for notifications and then send a test push from server everything works perfectly.

Same steps on Android Phone (Chrome 58) leads to a notification of "This site has been updated in the background." No title, no body text.

**Here's my `sw.js`:**

```
self.addEventListener("push", function(event) {
  if (event.data) {

    const data = event.data.text().split('\t') // [0] = title , [1] = body

    const options = {
        body: data[1],
    }

    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(data[0], options))

  } else {
    console.log("Push event but no data")
  }
})
```

**Log on server (`node.js` using `web-push`):**

```
{ statusCode: 201,
  body: '',
  headers:
   { location:
      'https://fcm.googleapis.com/0:15...',
     'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
     'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
     'x-xss-protection': '0',
     date: 'Tue, 10 Sep 2019 18:13:39 GMT',
     'content-length': '0',
     'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
     'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"',
     connection: 'close' } }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`"This site has been updated in the background."` is displayed when service worker has received a push but has not displayed it.

In my code I have an `else` block which skips showing the notification. Turns out, that's exactly where the code is ending up as it's missing data.

See [Missing push data on Android's PWA but not on Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57894583/missing-push-data-on-androids-pwa-but-not-on-desktop)