# Missing push data on Android's PWA but not on Desktop

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

**UPDATE:** Updating Chrome from 58 to 76 has resolved the issue. According to this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push#browser-support) Chrome v50+ supports payload which has not been the case here. Either there's a bug / issue with Chrome 58 or there's a bug somewhere in the code. *Still interested to learn which.*

I'm following the same procedure to send my push message for both Mobile and Desktop.

**Server (node.js):**

```
const webpush = require('web-push')

const vapidKeys = {
  publicKey:  '...',
  privateKey: '...',
}

webpush.setVapidDetails(
  'mailto:...',
  vapidKeys.publicKey,
  vapidKeys.privateKey
)

sendTestPush(user) {
  webpush.sendNotification(user.subscription,
  `Test Push Here!\nJust a test push!`)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
}
```

**Output:** (both Mobile and Desktop are similar)

```
{ statusCode: 201,
  body: '',
  headers:
   { location:
      'https://fcm.googleapis.com/0:15...',
     'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
     'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
     'x-xss-protection': '0',
     date: 'Tue, 10 Sep 2019 18:13:39 GMT',
     'content-length': '0',
     'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
     'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"',
     connection: 'close' } }
```

**service-worker.js:**

```
self.addEventListener("push", function(event) {
  const data = event.data ? event.data.text().split('\n') : ["Title", "Body"]
  const options = {
    body: data[1]
  }
  const promiseChain = self.registration.showNotification(data[0], options)
  event.waitUntil(promiseChain)
})
```

On Desktop I get:

```
Test Push Here!
  Just a test push!
```

On Mobile I get:

```
Title
  Body
```

which is being set by `service-worker.js` in case `event.data` is missing. What's causing data to be missing on the phone's PWA?

Comment: What browser and version is running on mobile? Not all [browsers support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push#browser-support) support payloads.

Comment: @abraham Chrome 58, which supports payloads.